# Как и чем распарсить строку JSON в VC++ .NET

Tags: .net, c++, visual-c++

После долгих попыток и неудач, после долгих поисков в гугле, у меня держится одна проблема, мне надо распарсить json строчку в масив, но все что я находил, было под СиШарп, может кто что подскажет?

P.S. Регулярки не предлагайте, т.к. количество элементов динамично...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Лучше нужно искать! Вот раз: [A JSON parser in C++](https://github.com/hjiang/jsonxx).

А [тут](http://json.org/) под все возможные языки. Выбирай - не хочу:)